# Canceling jQuery UI Accordion sections opening

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I use jQuery UI accordion widget, and I wonder if it is possible to cancel opening action using accordion's `changestart` event. From documentation:

```
// This event is triggered every time the accordion starts to change.
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
   changestart: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

And `event` contains `result` attribute. I guess I can use this attribute to cancel event, but what value I have to use? And if it's the wrong way, how I can accomplish it another way?

Comment: Why do you want to cancel? WHat's the use of an accordion that can never be opened?

Comment: I want to pause it, load content dynamically for this section via AJAX call and then manually open this section.

Answer (score 0):

You could just load the content on the `create` event...this would load the data into the div when the accordion is created.

```
$('.selector').accordion({
    create : function(event,ui) {
        $('.some-div').load('/path/to/data');
    }
});
```

or you could probably load the content on page load before you make the accordion

```
$('.some-div').load('path/to/data');
$('.selector').accordion();
```

or you could send the whole html over and then make it an accordion

```
$('.selector').load('path/to/data').accordion();
```

in any case, if you need to refresh the data periodically, then load the div contents on load at some point, and setup a timeout to load the new data.

```
$(function() {
    $('.selector').accordion();

    //Update every minute
    (function updateDiv() {
        $('.some-div').load('path/to/data');
        setTimeout(updateDiv,60000);
    })();
});
```